# How to handle a large number of Cron jobs

Tags: php, mysql, cron

My webserver is running cpanel and has a Cron job module in it providing a GUI to add/remove/edit cron jobs.

**Problem:** I need to create a large number of cron jobs (more than 100). Each cronjob simply does a `wget <url>` to trigger a bunch of PHP functions. What will be the best way to manage them? The current problem with cPanel's Cron GUI is that there will be no organization in the cron jobs. If I have 5 related cron jobs, added seperately admist 100 other unrelated cron jobs, it will get harder to find these cron jobs in the long list of cron jobs.

Should I stick to cPanel's GUI? Or is there an alternative GUI with better features like folders or the ability to move cron jobs up and down the list? Or should I just have 1 cron job, which calls a PHP file that does the various `wget` in PHP using `CURL`, with a table and stores the jobs in a MySQL database, essentially creating my own version of cron that runs off a single cronjob which triggers every minute?

Comment: Are these urls on the local server? wget for that would using a nuke to swat a fly in the 3rd floor break room. WHy not simply invoke the scripts direct as CLI?

Comment: @Marc B You don't know his setup. He might be using a framework which can't be run from the CLI without laying hands on.

Comment: I have URLs on the same server (eg: `domain.com/function?var1=a&var2=b`) that when called, calls a PHP function that does what I want. How would I invoke the PHP function using CLI? I have access to the `exec` PHP function if thats what should be used. Since many of these PHP functions can be running at a time, if theres a lighter alternative to `wget` it'll be awesome!

Comment: Like so: php -f /home/httpd/domain/docs/index.php arg1 arg2 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try grouping them.

Say you have 10 groups of ten, depending on how you organise them.

Each one of the cron jobs calls a PHP script that calls 10 other PHP scripts.

If you need them run at different times you could do a simple check with `time()` to see which scripts should be called.

You could call them the other PHP scripts using cURL.

Make sure to set a large script timeout though, or you might end up with lots of things going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Could you create one job in CPanel that will run one script.

Then in that script you could create the logic to run the 100 scripts.

If they are to be run at different times then you could use `switch(time)`, or similar to manage  execution.